# panel.BackImageUrl not visible when printed

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, asp-classic

I’m creating an application using asp.net and C#. I got to a point where I need to output some date on an image. I created a panel and set that image as panel’s background and placed numerous labels in it. However, when I want to print that page background is not visible. I need to have that background visible. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with classic asp. [Please learn the difference](http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-26.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing it in the print screen because you haven't explicitly defined it in a `print` css rule.

Using [`@media print {}`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp) CSS rule you can apply the same style when you print, otherwise, you will not see things like background-images on your print-out.

*The `@media` rule allows different style rules for different media in the same style sheet.*

In your case, you can wrap the style you have for the image with a `@media screen and print{}` wrapper and you will see them when you print as you do on the screen.

```
@media screen and print {
  panel.BackImageUrl { background-image:url(...); }
}
```

Or you can make it different on your print-out. For example, the following will display the `font-size` in `14px` on the screen, but only `10px` when you print.

```
panel.BackImageUrl { 
    background-image:url(...); 
    font-size:14px;
}

@media print {
  panel.BackImageUrl { 
    background-image:url(...); 
    font-size:10px;
  }
}
```